# How to capture SQUID proxy traffic via tcpdump with actual information?

Tags: proxy, tcpdump, squid, http-proxy

I am using `squid` as proxy in a small setup having one internal NIC and one external NIC. Now using tcp, I can capture traffic on either side but there is some problem that I am facing. If I capture traffic of external NIC then it gave only external NIC IP as client IP and if I capture traffic from internal then destination IP is always SQUID internal IP. What I want is actual client and server IP. How I can do it?

My OS is CentOS 7.2

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're using a transparent proxy, the behaviour you're seeing is normal:

- clients connect to the proxy to retrieve content, so you see packets from the clients to the proxy and back;
- the proxy connects to the target servers on behalf of the clients, so you see packets from the proxy to the target servers and back.

At the IP level, there is no way of connecting the two. If your proxy is a caching proxy, then in some cases there won't be anything to connect: the proxy can service clients' requests itself if it has the information in its cache. But if you look inside the packets, you should find what you're looking for:

- requests from the clients to the proxy will contain the target server name (look for the `Host` HTTP header);
- requests from the proxy to the target server might (depending on your proxy configuration) contain the IP address of the client (look for the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header).

Note that in the second case, with a caching proxy you'll only find the IP address of the first client requesting a given cacheable resource.

If you're trying to handle encrypted connections things get a bit more complicated; I'll let you read up on that (see [Wireshark's page on the subject](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) and [Squid's](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/HTTPS))...

Comment: Yes I am using transparent proxy

Comment: Are you using a GRE tunnel or just DNAT/SNAT?

Comment: I am using DNAT/SNAT

Comment: Is NAT being done on the system running Squid, or is there a separate router?

Comment: No there is no seprate router

Comment: If using Cisco routers, I would advise using WCCP.

Comment: You can also run two instances of `tcpdump` on each interface, writing the captured data to a dump file. Then use `mergecap` (usually included in the `wireshark` package) to combine both dump files into one according to timestamp. then you can use `wireshark` (or `tcpdump` if you prefer) to examine the dump.

Comment: @wurtel I don't think that's the issue here, the problem is matching up ingress and egress traffic. In any case, on Linux you can also run `tcpdump -i any` to grab all traffic on all interfaces (in non-promiscuous mode, but that's not necessary here).